# continuity of composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know that compositions of continuous functions are continuous, e.g. if $f: X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$ are continuous, then the composition is a contonuous function $g \circ f:X \to Z$.

But what if I have a continuous function $f:D \to \mathbb{R^{d}}$ where $D \subset I \times \mathbb{R^{d}}$ and $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. In partiular, the function is of the type $f(s,u(s))$ and $u:I \to \mathbb{R^{d}}$ is continuous. So it takes in a single variable $s$ and another function dependent on that variable.

How can I show that $s \to f(s,u(s))$ is a continuous function of $s$?

Since $u$ is continuous, I know that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $\vert s-t \rvert<\delta \implies \sqrt{(u_{1}(s)-u_{1}(t))^2+...+(u_{d}(s)-u_{d}(t))^2}<\epsilon$.

Similarly, since $f$ is continuous,  $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \nu>0$ s.t. $\sqrt{(s-t)^2+(u_{1}(s)-u_{1}(t))^2+...+(u_{d}(s)-u_{d}(t))^2}<\nu \implies \sqrt{(f_{1}(s,u(s))-f_{1}(t,u(t)))^2+...+(f_{d}(s,u(s))-f_{d}(t,u(t)))^2}<\epsilon$.

We need to somehow pick $\delta$ such that $\sqrt{(f_{1}(s,u(s))-f_{1}(t,u(t)))^2+...+(f_{d}(s,u(s))-f_{d}(t,u(t)))^2}<\epsilon$ and using the fact that we can find a bound $\nu$ s.t. $\sqrt{(u_{1}(s)-u_{1}(t))^2+...+(u_{d}(s)-u_{d}(t))^2}<\epsilon$ is smaller than any value we'd like.

But I can't see how to do it. I am really confused. Can someone please show me how to do it?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $s_0\in I$. Then the map $s\mapsto\bigl(s,u(s)\bigr)$ is continuous at $s_0$ because, if $\varepsilon>0$ and if $\delta>0$ is such that$$\lvert s-s_0\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lVert u(s)-u(s_0)\bigr\rVert<\frac\varepsilon2,$$then$$\lvert s-s_0\rvert<\min\left\{\frac\varepsilon2,\delta\right\}\implies\bigl\lVert\bigl(s,u(s)\bigr)-(s_0,u(s_0)\bigr)\bigr\rVert<\varepsilon.$$So, $s\mapsto f\bigl(s,u(s)\bigr)$ is continuous, since it is the composition of two continuous functions.